# [FR] Tags in package documentation

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Unfortunately I didn't find how to post a feature-request for ros.org site, so post here. (this post is connected to my prev. question(http://answers.ros.org/question/51928/how-to-search-for-ros-packages/?comment=52006#comment-52006).

It seems to be a not bad idea to add a tag field to package manifest ? And then generate tag field on package's documentation page on ros.org site. It'd allowed user to use these tags to search for some specific category of packages.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52104/%5Bfr%5D-tags-in-package-documentation/) by [Alexander Petrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3939/alexander-petrov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This feature request could be added to catkin on github. Else you can suggest this for discussion here:

http://groups.google.com/group/ros-sig-buildsystem

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1